# How to present detailview after saving data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to automatically go to detailView after the data has been saved from a presentViewController.

Currently,
I am using NavigationController which is Master (UITableView) ->Detail (UITextView), so user can add data and saved onto sqLite, and after saving the data from a form, the form dismissed and MasterView appears.

What I want is, after saving data, the form is dismissed and automatically going to DetailView instead of the MasterView.

MasterViewController.m

```
- (void)addNew{
  AddFormController *addFormController = [[AddFormController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"AddFormView" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController* navContainer = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addFormController];
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Header-Blank.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
  [self.navigationController presentViewController:navContainer animated:YES completion:nil];
  [addFormController release];
}
```

AddFormController.m

```
 - (IBAction) saveTemplate {
   .... // Saving data onto Sqlite
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can present your `DetailViewController` in `MasterViewController`'s `viewDidAppear`.

However, since you don't want this to happen every time (e.g., presenting `DetailViewController` on launch of the app), you want to set a Boolean property flag like `dataSaved` in `MasterViewController` and execute my first paragraph only when the flag is `YES`. And you can set the flag to `YES` from `[AddFormController saveTemplate]`. How to do that? There are several ways but I would use delegate.

And don't forget to unset the flag once you present the `DetailViewController` from `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Great idea! I'll try the method later today.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should use this code.It is simpler than above.

Masterviewcontroller.m
- (void)addNew{
  AddFormController *addFormController = [[AddFormController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"AddFormView" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController* navContainer = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addFormController];
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Header-Blank.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
  [addFormController release];
}

AddFormController.m

 - (IBAction) saveTemplate {
   .... // Saving data onto Sqlite
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }

I think it will work better.
```